# Find element in Array with specific class name and get its ID

Tags: jquery

```
var foo = $(myArray).each(function() {
   $(this)...('.thisClass').attr('id');
});
```

I know this is butchered but how do I search through `myArray` and find the one element that has `thisClass` assigned to it and retrieve its `id`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use .filter()

if it is an array of dom elements then try

```
$(myArray).filter('.myclass').attr('id')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Vq8Tq/)

---

If myArray is a jQuery wrapper object then

```
var id = myArray.filter('.two').attr('id');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6Tfhx/)